# Testcafe: Is there a way to keep the logged-in session intact between pages?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using Instagram to explain my scenario. I login with a testUser id in Instagram.  I loop through a set of Instagram accounts (ex: https://www.instagram.com/some_page/).  Such direct URL's are passed from a JSON file.  I validate something on this page and move on to next page to perform same set of validations.

*My problem here is, the login block is executed for each data. I am unable to give it in Fixture section.  Is there anyway to keep the logged-in session intact when I move between pages.*

**Role code**

```
const testUser = Role('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/', async t => {
/* some code */
}, { preserveUrl: true });
```

**Fixture and BeforeEach:**

```
fixture`Instaa Test`
    .page`https://www.instagram.com/`

    .before(async t => {
    })

    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.setTestSpeed(0.3)
        await t.useRole(testUser)
        await t.maximizeWindow()
    })
```

**Test Block:**

```
dataSet.forEach(data => {
    test("Check Business Account", async t => {
    await t.navigateTo(data.pageURL);
    /* some code */
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue with the following code:

```
import { Role, Selector } from 'testcafe';

const testUser = Role('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/', async t => {
    const login = Selector('#react-root > section > main > div > article > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(2) > div > label > input');
    const password = Selector('#react-root > section > main > div > article > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > div > label > input');
    const submit = Selector('#react-root > section > main > div > article > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(4) > button');

    await t.typeText(login, 'my-login');
    await t.typeText(password, 'my-password');
    await t.click(submit);

    // NOTE: here is a workaround
    // await t.wait(10000);

}, { preserveUrl: true });

fixture `Instagram`
    .page`https://www.instagram.com/`
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.setTestSpeed(0.3);
        await t.useRole(testUser);
    });

test(`test1`, async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/');
    await t.wait(5000);
});

test(`test2`, async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/');
    await t.wait(5000);
});

test(`test3`, async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('https://www.instagram.com/neymarjr/');
    await t.wait(5000);
});
```

I created a separate ticket in the testcafe repository: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4978

To make this example work, you need to add extra time at the end of your role initializer. Uncomment the following code:

```
// NOTE: here is a workaround
// await t.wait(10000);
```