# TestCafe - How Do I Use Roles with auth0 login

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have an app with an auth0 login. I haven't been able to figure out how to make `t.useRole` in this scenario.

Fortunately, this is easy to reproduce. auth0 (the application) uses the same process. It fails the exact same way as my app.

**Expected Outcome**
 - User logs in
 - User goes to dashboard
 - User remains log in
 - User goes to dashboard again (second test)

**Actual**
 - User logs in
 - User goes to dashboard
 - User is no longer authenticated
 - User goes to login page

```js
import { Role, Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const getPageUrl = ClientFunction(() => window.location.href.toString());

const exampleRole: Role = Role('https://auth0.com/auth/login', async t => {
    const userNameInput = Selector('input').withAttribute('name', 'email');
    const passwordInput = Selector('input').withAttribute('name', 'password');
    const loginButton = Selector('button').withAttribute('name', 'submit');

    await t
        .wait(5000)
        .click(userNameInput)
        .typeText(userNameInput, userName)
        .click(passwordInput)
        .typeText(passwordInput, password)
        .click(loginButton);
})

fixture(`SAMPLE`)
    .page('https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard')
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.useRole(exampleRole)
    })

test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
        .expect(getPageUrl()).contains('dashboard')
});

test('My next test', async t => {
    await t
        .expect(getPageUrl()).contains('dashboard')
})
```

**Output**

````
 SAMPLE
 √ My first test
 × My next test

   1) AssertionError: expected

   'https://auth0.auth0.com/login?state=***&client=***&protocol=oauth2&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmanage.auth0.com%2Fcallback&scope=openid%20profile%20name%20email%20nickname%20created_at'
      to include 'dashboard'
    ```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue reported here: [Testcafe: Is there a way to keep the logged-in session intact between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131783/testcafe-is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-logged-in-session-intact-between-pages)

The workaround was to add a wait after *.click(loginButton)* in the Role block and set presreveUrl to true.

```
const exampleRole: Role = Role('https://auth0.com/auth/login', async t => {
    const userNameInput = Selector('input').withAttribute('name', 'email');
    const passwordInput = Selector('input').withAttribute('name', 'password');
    const loginButton = Selector('button').withAttribute('name', 'submit');

    await t
        .wait(5000)
        .click(userNameInput)
        .typeText(userNameInput, userName)
        .click(passwordInput)
        .typeText(passwordInput, password)
        .click(loginButton);
        .wait(10000);
}, { preserveUrl: true });
```

**Edited to include `preserveUrl: true`. Thanks @dapperdan1985.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck with this. I'm under the impression that TestCafe ignores third-party cookies,

Comment: Actually, this did in fact work. I also needed to pass the `{preserveUrl: true}` option and remove `.page()` from the fixture.

Comment: @dapperdan1985 seems like you should accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @RooseveltH! I meant to suggest @Janaaa edit the answer to include the tidbit in my last comment about also needing `{preserveUrl: true}`. Otherwise, the answer isn't complete and others who stumble across this scenario may still be stuck.

Comment: @dapperdan1985: edited to include this now. thanks.

Comment: Awesome! This really helped me. I didn't need the 5 second wait time though

Comment: Confirming adding the .wait and the preserveUrl worked for me. Thanks!