# How to encapsulate 'Role' functionality into page model to log in only once

Tags: testcafe

Currently we are using testcafe to implement our test cases, and we'd like to encapsulate some page models for reusing purpose. In testcafe there is a 'Role' functionality that we want to leverage in our 'log_in' function so that we could log in only once in each test suite. The page model code is like below:

**app.js**

```
  async _login(url, userName, password) {
    const userRole = Role(url, async (t) => {
      await t
        .typeText(this.user, userName)
        .typeText(this.password, password)
        .click(this.signIn)
        .expect(this.home.exists)
        .ok("The file icon should exist after logging on");
    }, { preserveUrl: true });
    await t.useRole(userRole);
  }
  
  async login1stApp() {
    await this._login(config.firstUrl, config.user, config.password)
  }

  async login2ndApp() {
    await this._login(config.secondUrl, config.user, config.password, 
  )
    }
```

And in the test code, we will simply reference this page model and execute login function in beforeEach hook:

**test.js**

```
fixture`check ui`.beforeEach(async (t) => {
  await app.login1stApp();
});

test(`test a`, async (t) => {
  ...
});

test(`test b`, async (t) => {
  ....
});
```

It seems that the 'Role' does not take effect. Instead of logging in only once, testcafe will log in for each test case every time.
Is there any solution to make the 'Role' work based on current implementation? Thanks!

Comment: Please see if the accepted answer in this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095153/testcafe-how-do-i-use-roles-with-auth0-login/62095262#62095262.  Check out the comments there too.

Comment: @Janaaaa, thanks for your reply! I realized that I made a mistake in _login function. For the Role I am using it should be singleton, but in the code I created the Role every time I call the _login function, which is unexpected. Everything is working fine after I changed the code to make _login function to use the same Role.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite your page model class so that the `t.useRole(role)` method call is placed in the `beforeEach` hook.

So, the fixed page model implementation will look as follows:

```js
import { Role, t } from 'testcafe';

class App {
    constructor() {
        this._login1AppRole = Role('https://example.com', async (t) => {
            await t.wait(1000);
        }, { preserveUrl: true });
    }

    async login1stApp() {
        await t.useRole(this._login1AppRole);
    }
}

export default new App();
```